# How to change function call to have a more OOP with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want have a function main that when it is called i will also call another functions. I want to make a code where each function has their own class and then at the end will be called from the main class.

[image: my original code]

I wanted to change it into class is_date() and class is_number()
I dont really have much expertise in OOP with pandas if there are any pointers i would like to know some. thanks!

Comment: "I want to make a code where each function has their own class." Why? OOP is not a goal in and of itself. That said, `is_number` is already a trivial wrapper around an existing method. You could practically have just written `is_number = str.isdigit`

Comment: Those should not be classes.  Those are functions.  They have no state  There is no reason to have objects.

Comment: And PLEASE do not post your code as images.  Cut-and-paste the code text, so we can cut-and-paste to make answers.

Comment: `is_date = re.compile(r"...").match` is very close to your definition as well.

Comment: I don't see any class here. You always invoke a function from another function, and it'd return you the value. And in your case, since you use Dataframe, you don't even have to return value, thanks to mutable property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't say "if xxxx is True" or "if xxxx is False".  Python lets things have "true-ish" and "false-ish" values without making that conversion.  And you usually don't need "if xxx:" / "return 1" / "else:" / "return 0".  Just return the thing you're testing.  So:

```
def is_date(s):
    return 1 if re.match(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}",s) else 0
def is_number(s):
    return int(s.isdigit())
```

As a side note, it's not usually very useful to have `is_date` and `is_number` as columns, since it's so trivial to compute those values when you need them.